# What is www.conf?

Tags: php, nginx

I know what `php.ini` is for which can be found in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm` directory

I can't find documentation what `www.conf` is designed for? It can be found in

```
/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d
```

Comment: Read this documentation http://myjeeva.com/php-fpm-configuration-101.html

Comment: `*.conf` are typically web server config files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pool Directives are a [PHP-FPM convention](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) where multiple "pools" of child processes can be started and have different configurations. The default name for the pool directives file is `www.conf`.

Take a look at [this link](http://myjeeva.com/php-fpm-configuration-101.html#pool-directives) for more information and sample configurations.